# how to create pc calculator script in php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have 2 tables one is category and one is products. Now I want to PC calculator.

I have all the fields generated dynamically based on the database. So how can I write script to make like this.

```
<table ALIGN=CENTER WIDTH=100% BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=1 CELLPADDING=3>
    <tr>
        <th>Category Name</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>           
    <tr class="odd">
        <td>Speaker</td>
        <td>
            <select name="1" size="1" id="1">
                <option value="1200.00">intex</option>
                <option value="2100.00">creative</option>
                <option value="1400.00">intex 2.1</option>
                <option value="2000.00">intex 2.1 with woofer</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><div id="t1" class="price">0</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td>Laptop</td> 
        <td>
            <select name="3" size="1" id="3">
                <option value="31000.00">sony</option>
                <option value="31500.00">hp</option>
                <option value="31000.00">Acer</option>
                <option value="36000.00">ibm</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><div id="t1" class="price">0</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td>Mouse</td>
        <td>
            <select name="4" size="1" id="4">
                <option value="120.00"> teccom</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><div id="t1" class="price">0</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td>CPU</td>
        <td>
            <select name="6" size="1" id="6">
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><div id="t1" class="price">0</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td>Projector</td>
        <td>
            <select name="7" size="1" id="7">
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><div id="t1" class="price">0</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td>Anti Virus</td>
        <td>
            <select name="23" size="1" id="23">
                <option value="450.00">McAfee</option>
                <option value="1200.00">AVG</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><div id="t1" class="price">0</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td>Processor</td>
        <td>
            <select name="59" size="1" id="59">
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><div id="t1" class="price">0</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td>testing</td>
        <td>
            <select name="60" size="1" id="60">
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><div id="t1" class="price">0</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td>sadfasdfasdfadsfad</td>
        <td>
            <select name="61" size="1" id="61">
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><div id="t1" class="price">0</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td>dfgd</td>
        <td>
            <select name="62" size="1" id="62">
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><div id="t1" class="price">0</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td><div id="total"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

here is jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sellp").change(function () {
        var str = 0.00;
        $("#sellp :selected").each(function () {
            var test = $(this).val();
            //alert(test);
            var tr = parseInt(str) + parseInt(test);
            //alert(tr);
            $("#t1").text(test);
        });
    });
    var sum = 0;
    $("form :element").change(function() {
        $('.price').each(function() {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });
    $('#total').html(sum) });
});
```

Comment: Most of this app is JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: yes I know, I use php because my application is in php. so how can I make it using javascript

Comment: Yes, you can., learn JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly show some code.

Assuming all items are in the page when it loads, you need to add some event handlers

Here is plain JS - jQuery may be more elegant. You will likely need to start with this and then add the validation. You will make your life much easier if you name your fields in a way that is easy to get to

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function calc(theForm) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i=1;;i++) {
    var item = theForm.elements["item_"+i];
    if (item) {
      var price =  item.options[item.selectedIndex].value;
      if (price && !isNaN(price)) {
        price = parseFloat(price);
        total+=price;
        var priceId = item.id.replace('item','price');
        document.getElementById(priceId).innerHTML=price.toFixed(2);
      }
    }
    else break;
  }
  if (total) document.getElementById('total').innerHTML="$"+total.toFixed(2);
}
window.onload=function() {
  var theForm = document.forms[0]; // first form on page
  for (var i=0,n=theForm.elements.length;i<n;i++) {
   if (theForm.elements[i].type.indexOf("select") !=-1)  {
      theForm.elements[i].onchange=function() { calc(this.form); }
    }
  }
  theForm.onsubmit=function() { calc(this); return validate(this) }
  calc(theForm)
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<table   ALIGN=CENTER WIDTH=100% BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=1 CELLPADDING=3 >
                             <tr>
                             <th>Category Name</th>

                             <th>Product Name</th>  

                             <th>Price</th>
                             </tr>           
                                                        <tr class="odd">
                            <td>Speaker </td>


                            <td><select name="item_1" size="1" id="item_1">
                                                            <option value="1200.00"> intex</option>

                                                            <option value="2100.00"> creative</option>
                                                            <option value="1400.00"> intex 2.1</option>
                                                            <option value="2000.00"> intex 2.1 with woofer</option>

                            </select>                           
                            </td>
                            <td><div id="price_1" class="price">0</div></td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr class="odd">
                            <td>Laptop </td>


                            <td><select name="item_2" size="1" id="item_2">
                                                            <option value="31000.00"> sony</option>
                                                            <option value="31500.00"> hp</option>

                                                            <option value="31000.00"> Acer</option>
                                                            <option value="36000.00"> ibm</option>

                            </select>                           
                            </td>
                            <td><div id="price_2" class="price">0</div></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="odd">

                            <td>Mouse </td>


                            <td><select name="item_3" size="1" id="item_3">
                                                            <option value="120.00"> teccom</option>

                            </select>                           
                            </td>
                            <td><div id="price_3" class="price">0</div></td>
                            </tr>

</table>
</form>
Total: <span id="total"></span>
```

Comment: Hi mplungjan, I have added my code, I am using jQuery but can't able to get dynamically generated ids for select.

Comment: You do not need them. The code keeps calling with the form object. Please show the html generated rather than the PHP. I suggest plain JS rather than jQuery here

Comment: you need to match the price cell IDs to the select IDs first

Comment: @PHP Please see update - especially how I match the name/id of the field to the id of the price cell